# How to access control from another thread? C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How to change label in UserControl in UserControl from another thread?

Here is my code:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
                  new DelegateMethod(() => {
                    App.mainWindow.FirstUserControl.SecondUserControl.txtLbl.Content = "Hello!";
                  }));
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "The thread calling this cannot access the specified object because the object is owned by another thread."
```

Comment: This looks about right on first glance. What's your problem?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: "The thread calling this cannot access the specified object because the object is owned by another thread."

Comment: Are you sure you are running that code and not an old version? Does it compile? Do you run the correct build?

Comment: Yes, i am sure.

Comment: I guess you need to build a [mre] then...

Comment: It looks almost as if the second user control was created on a different thread than the first control.  Ifs that the case?  If so, get the text out of the second user control into a `string` object on your current thread and then send that as a string to the `Dispatcher.Invoke` call.